# Is it possible to pass filter function results column into product function?

Tags: excel

Hi is it possible to do something among this lines

```
=product(
   filter(
            data,
            data<>false,
            FALSE
   )[some_column_with_numbers_to_be_multiplied]
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it should be possible. Try like-

```
=PRODUCT(FILTER(F1:F10,G1:G10="a"),E1:E5)
```

[image]